# Выбор архитектуры для нейро-сети

Tags: нейронные-сети

Какая архитектура (топология) нейро-сети лучше всего подходит для выполнения задачи прогнозирования временных рядов ?

UPD
Сейчас я пытаюсь написать сеть, которая умеет угадывать значения от 0 до 9 в простом ряду := 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-1... и т.д. В сети есть 3 входных, 3 скрытых и 4 выходных нейрона.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На входы входных нейронов подаются данные о 3х прошлых значениях (i-1,i-2,i-3) на их основании сеть должна принять решение о следующем значении. Значения на выходах O1-O4 округляются и соответствуют числу в двоичной системе, например если округленные значения O1=0; O2=1; O3=0; O4=0 то ответ сети будет 4. Пока все просто, набрал модель сети в C# и получаю совсем непонятные результаты. Например, если я пытаюсь научить сеть выдавать мне 4, если на входы подаются 3,2 и 1 то график ошибок по числу испытаний выглядит так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. хорошо, уже через ~100 испытаний и пересчетов весов сеть понимает, что после 1-2-3 должно идти 4. Но если я пытаюсь, как и задумывалось научить ее строить простой временной ряд то сходимости и близко нет :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может я провожу слишком мало испытаний или вообще неверную архитектуру выбрал ?

Answer (score 2):

Нужна сеть, где простым языком, возможны циклы и имеется возможность в нейронах возвращать часть информации на вход и за счет этого получать информацию о событиях произошедших какое-то время назад.

Если зашумленность данных минимальна, то прогнозирование временных рядов обычно производится при помощи многослойных перцептронов и метода обратного распространения ошибки, но временные ряды сами по себе довольно зашумлены, поэтому такой вид будет обладать довольно низкой точностью.

Я бы на вашем месте определенно взял рекуррентную топологию. По сути, смысл в том, что на каждом временном отрезке входные данные распределяются по нейронам в прямом направлении, затем на них применяется обучающее правило. Благодаря фиксированным обратным связям, контекстные элементы всегда хранят копию значений из скрытого слоя за предыдущий шаг.

Самой первой РНС была сеть **Хопфилда** (1982 год), потом сеть **Элмана**, которую признано считать эволюционной в развитии РНС (1990 год), и основой для всех текущих сетей используемых в задаче предсказания является **LSTM** описанный в 1997 году Хохрейтером и Шмидхубером.

**LSTM**, вроде как наиболее популярная сеть для предсказания временных рядов. Конечно задача предсказания временных рядов - это довольно сложный тип исследования, поэтому наряду с нейронными сетями могут использоваться уже ранее используемые математические модели создавая некоторую гибридную систему.

Безусловно у LSTM есть модификации, но стоит начать именно с этой сети, ведь для нее достаточно большое количество обучающих материалов.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, не могли бы вы посмотреть на графики ?

Comment: Нужно понять - ошибка именно в архитектуре и такая сеть в принципе не способна ничего предсказать или в коде или в самом процессе обучения?